# Dynamic Role based Authorization in Blazor Server

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm new to blazor server. I have implemented asp.net core identity role-based authorization. But I don't want to hardcode roles on the Authorize attribute. I want to create roles later and specify in which controller and action it has access without touching source code.

[image]

As you can see in the image above how can I create dynamic role based authorization in blazor server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement and Authorize via a policy.

You can create a permission that can be assigned to any `Role`. In combination with a `Policy` that checks for the permission.

This allows you to create roles at runtime and assign permissions to these new roles. When a user is then assigned a role the policy will see the permissions attached to the role.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Your screen would become groupings of 6 permissions that would be assigned to each role. Which would require 6 Policies.

I would consider using a class like the following:

`Permission.cs`

```
public sealed class Permission
{
    public static readonly IReadOnlyList<Permission> Permissions = new List<Permission>
    { RolesView, RolesCreate, RolesUpdate, RolesDelete, UserRoleView, UserRoleUpdate };

    public static explicit operator string(Permission p) => p.Key;

    public static Permission RolesView => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.Roles.View",
        Display = "Role List",
        GroupName = "Role Management"
    };
    public static Permission RolesCreate => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.Roles.Create",
        Display = "Create Role",
        GroupName = "Role Management"
    };
    public static Permission RolesUpdate => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.Roles.Update",
        Display = "Edit Role",
        GroupName = "Role Management"
    };
    public static Permission RolesDelete => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.Roles.Delete",
        Display = "Delete",
        GroupName = "Role Management"
    };
    public static Permission UserRoleView => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.UserRole.View",
        Display = "User List",
        GroupName = "User Role Management"
    };
    public static Permission UserRoleUpdate => new Permission
    {
        Key = "Permission.UserRole.Update",
        Display = "Edit User Roles",
        GroupName = "User Role Management"
    };

    public string Key { get; private set; }
    public string Display { get; private set; }
    public string GroupName { get; private set; }
}
```

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    ...
    options.AddPolicy(name: "UserRoleView", policy =>
            policy.RequireClaim(Permission.UserRoleView));
    ...
});
```

```
[Authorize(Policy = "UserRoleView")]
```

Use the `RoleManager`s methods `AddClaimAsync` & `RemoveClaimAsync` using the `Permission` as the claim exploiting the explicit string conversion.

Answer (score 1):

As an add on to Brian's answer, there's a `PolicyBuilder` factory that you can use to build out your policies.  Here's a simple example from one of my applications:

```cs
public static class AppPolicies
{
    public const string IsAdmin = "IsAdmin";
    public const string IsUser = "IsUser";
    public const string IsVisitor = "IsVisitor";

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsAdminPolicy
        => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin")
        .Build();

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsUserPolicy
        => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin", "User")
        .Build();

    public static AuthorizationPolicy IsVisitorPolicy
        => new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .RequireRole("Admin", "User", "Visitor")
        .Build();

    public static Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy> Policies
    {
        get
        {
            var policies = new Dictionary<string, AuthorizationPolicy>();
            policies.Add(IsAdmin, IsAdminPolicy);
            policies.Add(IsUser, IsUserPolicy);
            policies.Add(IsVisitor, IsVisitorPolicy);
            return policies;
        }
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```cs
        services.AddAuthorization(config =>
        {
            foreach (var policy in AppPolicies.Policies) 
            {
                config.AddPolicy(policy.Key, policy.Value);
            }
        });
```